# Why does Web Streams API lack Duplex Stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, whatwg-streams-api

I am familiar with the "old" nodejs stream, so the need of [Duplex steam](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#types-of-streams)  "streams that are both Readable and Writable (for example, net.Socket)" seem quite obvious.

[To quote](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamduplex)

> Examples of Duplex streams include:
>
> 1. TCP sockets
> 2. zlib streams
> 3. crypto streams

When I am studying nodejs18 new features and find nodejs has added [Web Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API). I was a bit surprised to see web streams only has [3 steam types](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html#overview), i.e. it lacks of **Duplex** stream. I notice it is because https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/ only defines 3 types of streams. But why ? Doesn't the need for a both Readable and Writable stream obvious?

Answer (score 3):

A duplex stream is any object with a `readable` property that is a `ReadableStream`, and a `writable` property that is a `WritableStream`. Since it is easy to create objects with two properties in JavaScript (use the syntax `{ readable, writable }`), there is no need for a class or other helper. So the standard does not include one.

The standard gives more information on this in https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#other-specs-duplex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have a feeling that the standard api always likes to keep a bit distance from the existing nodejs api.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking into this right now, and yes there's no equivalent to `Duplex`  for the web streams, however you create your own by doing something like this:

```
class MyStream<R = any, W = any> implements ReadableWritablePair<R, W> {
  public readable: ReadableStream<R>;
  public writable: WritableStream<W>;
  public constructor() {
    this.readable = new ReadableStream();
    this.writable = new WritableStream();
  }
}
```

Then implement each side independently.

Comment: Or you could just do `{ readable: new ReadableStream(), writable: new WritableStream() }`. This class is extra complicated for no real purpose.

Comment: I needed the class for other reasons cause my stream contains other special states/properties.